# Why ready function on my SettingsFlout not getting hit?

Tags: javascript, windows-8, windows-runtime, winjs, application-settings

I have implemented a SettingsFlyout. From the view of this flyout, my app collection some info from user (firsname) and want to store it in roaming settings. This information get stored when user clicks a button the settings view and retrieved when in the beforeShow event for the flyout. These two events are setup in the ready function of the SettingsFlyout itself but for some reason this ready function is not been called. As a result the events are not result and not been invoked. Let me show you the code now. Here is what I have in default.html

```
app.onsettings = function (e) {

        e.detail.applicationcommands = {
            "test": {
                href: "/pages/settings/test/test.html",
                title: "Test"
            }
        }

        WinJS.UI.SettingsFlyout.populateSettings(e);
    };
```

Here is the test.html itself.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <link href="/pages/settings/test/test.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div 
            data-win-control="WinJS.UI.SettingsFlyout"  data-win-options="{settingsCommandId:'test',  width:'narrow'}">
            <div class="win-header">       
                <div class="win-label">test</div>
            </div>
            <div class="win-content">
                First Name: <input id="firstname" />
                <br />
                <input type="submit" value="Save" />
            </div>
        </div>  
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the test.js file.

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    WinJS.UI.Pages.define("/pages/settings/test/test.html", {
        // This function is called whenever a user navigates to this page. It
        // populates the page elements with the app's data.
        ready: function (element, options) {
            // TODO: Initialize the page here.
            var roamingSettings = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.current.roamingSettings;
            var divtest = document.getElementById("test").winControl;
            var firstname = document.getElementById("firstname");

            document.getElementById("submit").onclick = function (e) {
                //alert('hi');
                roamingSettings.values["firstname"] = firstname.value;
            }

            divtest.addEventListener("beforeshow", function () {
                firstname.value = roamingSettings.values["firstname"];
            });
        },

        unload: function () {
            // TODO: Respond to navigations away from this page.
        },

        updateLayout: function (element, viewState, lastViewState) {
            /// <param name="element" domElement="true" />

            // TODO: Respond to changes in viewState.
        }
    });
})();
```

What am  I doing wrong here and how can I ready function called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

looks like `<script>` tag for `test.js` is missing in test.html

```
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link href="/pages/settings/test/test.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="/pages/settings/test/test.js"></script>
</head>
```

regards comments. html has missing `id` attributes for those elements. hence, `getElementById` is failing. Having said that `document.getElementById()` is not necessarily the best way to achieve that. consider using `class` attribute in html and `element.querySelector('.myclass')` which scopes the query to the root element for the page; also scope of collision of ids across pages is removed.

```
<div id="test"
        data-win-control="WinJS.UI.SettingsFlyout"  data-win-   options="{settingsCommandId:'test',  width:'narrow'}">
        <div class="win-header">       
            <div class="win-label">test</div>
        </div>
        <div class="win-content">
            First Name: <input id="firstname" />
            <br />
            <input id='submit' type="submit" value="Save"
```